# Chisel Bundle connection and type Safety

Tags: chisel

Just noticed you can do something like:

```
class MyBundle1 extends Bundle {
  val a = Bool()
  val x = UInt(2.W)
  val y = Bool()
}

class MyBundle2 extends Bundle {
  val x = Bool()
  val y = Bool()
}

class Foo extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(new MyBundle1)
    val out = Output(new MyBundle2)
  })

  io.out := io.in
}
```

not get an error and actually get the correct or, at least, expected verilog. One would think that Chisel was type-safe wrt to Bundles in this sort of bulk connection. Is this intentional? If so, is there any particular reasons for it?

Answer (score 3):

The semantics of `:=` on `Bundle` allow the RHS to have fields that are not present on the LHS, but not vice-versa. The high-level description of `x := y` is "drive all fields of x with corresponding fields of y."

The bi-directional `<>` operator is stricter.

I can't speak precisely to the reasoning, but connection operators are often a matter of taste with respect to "do what I mean." The idea of including alternate forms of connection operators for future releases is an ongoing discussion, with the threat of "operator glut" being weighed against the ability of users to specify exactly what they'd like to do.

Comment: I get one can have fields on the RHS not present in the LHS. But this was not the main point of my question.  What I meant is that these are different types being connected, with no direct base/derived class relationship. For example, although Chisel allows you to connect a Bool to a UInt (its parent class, I believe), it does not allow you to do the same with SInt. So why should this connection be allowed just because the bundles have fields with the same name?

Comment: Connections of bundles are checked in a manner similar to "structural typing" in software -- if two bundles have all identically-named fields (or the LHS has a subset of the RHS's fields) and all those fields are connectable, those bundles are connectable.

Comment: One interesting aspect (for better or for worse) of Chisel is that many operators are less strict than they could be. However, the Scala metaprogramming that Chisel allows is generally easy to make arbitrarily strict and intrinsically type-safe. Therefore, it's a common pattern to layer stricter methods on top of the built-in Chisel API. In theory, this gives users fine-grained control when they want it and lets them build safe APIs if they don't; however, it does have the significant downside of making operators less intuitive than they could be.

Comment: Future releases may include constrained assignment operators or a "strict mode." I'll circle back and comment here when there's a good Github issue link.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!